# FollowJointTrajectory Usage

Tags: ros, pr2-arm-navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On the PR2, the joint controller provides two different actions, JointTrajectoryAction and a the new FollowJointTrajectory. Is there any documentation on how to use this action? I've run both and seem to get the same trajectories with the different JointTolerances I've tried.

Running electric on a PR2. Relevant links: [control_msgs](http://www.ros.org/wiki/control_msgs#), [FollowJointTrajectoryAction](http://www.ros.org/doc/electric/api/control_msgs/html/msg/FollowJointTrajectoryAction.html).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11712/followjointtrajectory-usage/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2011-10-27

Post score: 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See my answer to this question: http://answers.ros.org/question/2765/where-is-the-node-for-follow_joint_trajectory

We'll try and put up some Wiki documentation soon.

---

Originally posted by [Sachin Chitta](https://answers.ros.org/users/39/sachin-chitta/) with karma: 1304 on 2011-11-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on 2011-11-06**:
The other useful bit that I got from Stu offline is "The short version is that FollowJointTrajectory adds tolerances that,
when violated, cause the trajectory to abort"

**Comment by [Alxander19](https://answers.ros.org/users/20905/alxander19/) on 2020-03-30**:
Still no answer?